# Flink Statefun API Kafka trigger

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-statefun

I want to implement a job using the Apache Flink Statefun API and configure Kafka as a trigger. The idea is have events go into a Kafka topic, and have it then trigger a stateful function in Flink like a FaaS. Is this possible? How would it be implemented? I looked at the Kafka IO documentation but couldn't find any concrete code examples so if anyone has a simple example it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly what the [Kafka ingress](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-statefun-docs-master/docs/modules/io/apache-kafka/) does.

There's a complete example application in https://github.com/ververica/flink-statefun-workshop that uses Kafka.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any chance of a Java example?

Comment: I haven't seen a Java example that uses Kafka. Conceptually it fits in the same way, but if you are using embedded Java functions the details of setting up the routing will be a bit different, I believe.